# Is まで inclusive or exclusive when marking a range of dates?

Tags: time

I've recently received a notice from a library.  It says:

> あなたへの貸し出しは2013/02/13まで停止されています。

Should I visit the library on 13 or 14 of February?  To put it another way, does `まで` include the date before it or not?

Comment: Could this be phrased something like: "Is まで inclusive or exclusive when marking a range of dates?"  I'm trying to think of how this question could be more easily found by others in the future.

Comment: @snailplane: feel free to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that it is a notice received from a library (please include the context in the question).  The notice means that borrowing by you is suspended until Feb. 13, inclusive, and therefore you cannot check out library materials on Feb. 13.

An example from [*Catch a Wave*](http://catchawave.jp/), April 13, 2012, via [Space ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E9%96%8B%E5%82%AC%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B):

> 毎年恒例のニューヨーク国際自動車ショーが今年は4月6日から15日まで開催されている。  The annual New York International Auto Show runs from April 6 to 15 this year.

Comment: With respect, the context was clear enough.

Comment: @user18597: Although the context is clear to those who know Japanese enough, that is not a valid reason not to include the context in the question.  If you want others to treat your questions seriously, you should not be lazy when stating questions.

Comment: Tsuyoshi, perhaps you could have included the context in comment or edit to the original question, and in your answer just addressed whether まで is always inclusive or not. As it is I don't know from your answer.